# IOS Stack View Basics

Tags: ios, uistackview

Learning stack view; what's preventing this horizontal line of 60x60 buttons from a) all showing up on both screens (constraints are set on the trailing side so I'm not sure why it's going past the right edge of the screen), and b) scaling the buttons larger.  I'm looking to see all the buttons and scale them proportionately to the screen size while maintaining their individual aspect ratios.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Put an “aspect ratio “ constraint in each one of them.

2- Put constraints on stack view “leading” and “trailing”.

3- In the attributes inspector for stack view make all views “Equal “ instead of “Fill”.

These setting will make all of them appear with the same size and  according to the screen size they will vary but still all of them with the same aspect ratio.

Comment: Aspect ratio on each button is not necessary if the stackView is fillEqually and constrained properly.. Can possibly also just aspect the stackView.

Comment: Aspect ratio needed to avoid any problems if he puts the stack constraints values wrong ( It keeps the shape on its ratio whatever the height of stack ) Note that if he put the stack Fill equally , the problem will be in the height thats why its better to take aspect ratio in consideration from the beginning.